# V8 package causes R session to terminate on Manjaro linux

Tags: r, shiny, v8, archlinux, manjaro

I recently switched to Manjaro Linux and I couldn't run a Shiny app which uses extendedjs from shinyjs package. Every time the R session was aborted (wit the message R encountered a fatal error The session was terminated).
I managed to narrow down the problem to V8 rpackage. When I run it in R console (i.e. outside Rstudio) I get the same error with the folowing trace:

```
V8::v8()

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:

1:.Call("V8_make_context", PACKAGE = "V8", set_console)
2:make_context(private$console)
3:reset()
4:eval(quote({
  eval <-
    function(src) {
      get_str_output(context_eval(join(src), private$context))
    }    validate <-
      function(src) {
        context_validate(join(src), private$context)
      }    call <-
        function(fun, ..., auto_unbox = TRUE) {
          stopifnot(is.character(fun))        stopifnot(this$validate(c("fun=", fun)))        jsargs <-
            list(...)        if (!is.null(names(jsargs))) {
              stop("Named arguments are not supported in JavaScript.")
            }        jsargs <-
              vapply(jsargs, function(x) {
                if (is.atomic(x) &&
                    inherits(x, "JS_EVAL")) {
                  as.character(x)
                } else {
                  toJSON(x, auto_unbox = auto_unbox)
                }
              }, character(1))        jsargs <-
                paste(jsargs, collapse = ",")        src <-
                  paste0("JSON.stringify((", fun, ")(", jsargs,             "));")        out <-
                    this$eval(src)        get_json_output(out)
        }    source <-
          function(file) {
            if (is.character(file) &&
                length(file) == 1 &&
                grepl("^https?://",             file)) {
              file <-
                curl(file, open = "r")            on.exit(close(file))
            }        this$eval(readLines(file, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE))
          }    get <-
            function(name, ...) {
              stopifnot(is.character(name))        get_json_output(this$eval(c("JSON.stringify(", name,             ")")), ...)
            }    assign <-
              function(name, value, auto_unbox = TRUE, ...) {
                stopifnot(is.character(name))        obj <-
                  if (inherits(value, "JS_EVAL")) {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste("var", name, "=", value)))
                  } else {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste(
                      "var",
                      name,
                      "=",
                      toJSON(value,                 auto_unbox = auto_unbox, ...)
                    )))
                  }
              }    reset <-
                function() {
                  private$context <-
                    make_context(private$console)        private$created <-
                      Sys.time()        if (length(global)) {
                        context_eval(paste("var", global, "= this;", collapse = "\n"),
                                     private$context)
                      }        if (isTRUE(typed_arrays)) {
                        context_enable_typed_arrays(private$context)
                      }        invisible()
                }    console <-
                  function() {
                    this$eval("")        message("This is V8 version ", version(), ". Press ESC or CTRL+C to exit.")        on.exit(message("Exiting V8 console."))        buffer <-
                      character()        has_history <-
                        !inherits(try(savehistory(tempfile()),             silent = T)
                                  , "try-error")        if (has_history) {
                                    savehistory()            on.exit(loadhistory(), add = TRUE)            histfile <-
                                      ".V8history"            if (file.exists(histfile)) {
                                        loadhistory(histfile)
                                      } else {
                                        file.create(histfile)
                                      }
                                  }        rc.options(
                                    custom.completer = function(env) {
                                      env$comps <-
                                        tab_complete(this, env$token)
                                    }
                                  )        on.exit({
                                    rc.options(custom.completer = NULL)
                                  }, add = TRUE)        repeat {
                                    prompt <-
                                      ifelse(length(buffer), "  ", "~ ")            if (nchar(line <-
                                                                                              readline(prompt))) {
                                        buffer <-
                                          c(buffer, line)
                                      }            if (identical(buffer, "exit"))
                                        break            if (length(buffer) &&
                                                             (this$validate(buffer) ||
                                                              !nchar(line))) {
                                          if (has_history) {
                                            write(buffer, histfile, append = TRUE)                  loadhistory(histfile)
                                          }                tryCatch(
                                            cat(undefined_to_null(this$eval(buffer))),
                                            error = function(e) {
                                              message(e$message)
                                            }
                                          )                buffer <-
                                            character()
                                        }
                                  }
                  }    reset()    lockEnvironment(environment(), TRUE)    structure(environment(), class = c("V8", "environment"))
}), new.env())
5:eval(quote({
  eval <-
    function(src) {
      get_str_output(context_eval(join(src), private$context))
    }    validate <-
      function(src) {
        context_validate(join(src), private$context)
      }    call <-
        function(fun, ..., auto_unbox = TRUE) {
          stopifnot(is.character(fun))        stopifnot(this$validate(c("fun=", fun)))        jsargs <-
            list(...)        if (!is.null(names(jsargs))) {
              stop("Named arguments are not supported in JavaScript.")
            }        jsargs <-
              vapply(jsargs, function(x) {
                if (is.atomic(x) &&
                    inherits(x, "JS_EVAL")) {
                  as.character(x)
                } else {
                  toJSON(x, auto_unbox = auto_unbox)
                }
              }, character(1))        jsargs <-
                paste(jsargs, collapse = ",")        src <-
                  paste0("JSON.stringify((", fun, ")(", jsargs,             "));")        out <-
                    this$eval(src)        get_json_output(out)
        }    source <-
          function(file) {
            if (is.character(file) &&
                length(file) == 1 &&
                grepl("^https?://",             file)) {
              file <-
                curl(file, open = "r")            on.exit(close(file))
            }        this$eval(readLines(file, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE))
          }    get <-
            function(name, ...) {
              stopifnot(is.character(name))        get_json_output(this$eval(c("JSON.stringify(", name,             ")")), ...)
            }    assign <-
              function(name, value, auto_unbox = TRUE, ...) {
                stopifnot(is.character(name))        obj <-
                  if (inherits(value, "JS_EVAL")) {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste("var", name, "=", value)))
                  } else {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste(
                      "var",
                      name,
                      "=",
                      toJSON(value,                 auto_unbox = auto_unbox, ...)
                    )))
                  }
              }    reset <-
                function() {
                  private$context <-
                    make_context(private$console)        private$created <-
                      Sys.time()        if (length(global)) {
                        context_eval(paste("var", global, "= this;", collapse = "\n"),
                                     private$context)
                      }        if (isTRUE(typed_arrays)) {
                        context_enable_typed_arrays(private$context)
                      }        invisible()
                }    console <-
                  function() {
                    this$eval("")        message("This is V8 version ", version(), ". Press ESC or CTRL+C to exit.")        on.exit(message("Exiting V8 console."))        buffer <-
                      character()        has_history <-
                        !inherits(try(savehistory(tempfile()),             silent = T)
                                  , "try-error")        if (has_history) {
                                    savehistory()            on.exit(loadhistory(), add = TRUE)            histfile <-
                                      ".V8history"            if (file.exists(histfile)) {
                                        loadhistory(histfile)
                                      } else {
                                        file.create(histfile)
                                      }
                                  }        rc.options(
                                    custom.completer = function(env) {
                                      env$comps <-
                                        tab_complete(this, env$token)
                                    }
                                  )        on.exit({
                                    rc.options(custom.completer = NULL)
                                  }, add = TRUE)        repeat {
                                    prompt <-
                                      ifelse(length(buffer), "  ", "~ ")            if (nchar(line <-
                                                                                              readline(prompt))) {
                                        buffer <-
                                          c(buffer, line)
                                      }            if (identical(buffer, "exit"))
                                        break            if (length(buffer) &&
                                                             (this$validate(buffer) ||
                                                              !nchar(line))) {
                                          if (has_history) {
                                            write(buffer, histfile, append = TRUE)                  loadhistory(histfile)
                                          }                tryCatch(
                                            cat(undefined_to_null(this$eval(buffer))),
                                            error = function(e) {
                                              message(e$message)
                                            }
                                          )                buffer <-
                                            character()
                                        }
                                  }
                  }    reset()    lockEnvironment(environment(), TRUE)    structure(environment(), class = c("V8", "environment"))
}), new.env())
6:eval(expr, p)
7:eval(expr, p)
8:eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
9:local({
  eval <-
    function(src) {
      get_str_output(context_eval(join(src), private$context))
    }    validate <-
      function(src) {
        context_validate(join(src), private$context)
      }    call <-
        function(fun, ..., auto_unbox = TRUE) {
          stopifnot(is.character(fun))        stopifnot(this$validate(c("fun=", fun)))        jsargs <-
            list(...)        if (!is.null(names(jsargs))) {
              stop("Named arguments are not supported in JavaScript.")
            }        jsargs <-
              vapply(jsargs, function(x) {
                if (is.atomic(x) &&
                    inherits(x, "JS_EVAL")) {
                  as.character(x)
                }            else {
                  toJSON(x, auto_unbox = auto_unbox)
                }
              }, character(1))        jsargs <-
                paste(jsargs, collapse = ",")        src <-
                  paste0("JSON.stringify((", fun, ")(", jsargs,             "));")        out <-
                    this$eval(src)        get_json_output(out)
        }    source <-
          function(file) {
            if (is.character(file) &&
                length(file) == 1 &&
                grepl("^https?://",             file)) {
              file <-
                curl(file, open = "r")            on.exit(close(file))
            }        this$eval(readLines(file, encoding = "UTF-8", warn = FALSE))
          }    get <-
            function(name, ...) {
              stopifnot(is.character(name))        get_json_output(this$eval(c("JSON.stringify(", name,             ")")), ...)
            }    assign <-
              function(name, value, auto_unbox = TRUE, ...) {
                stopifnot(is.character(name))        obj <-
                  if (inherits(value, "JS_EVAL")) {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste("var", name, "=", value)))
                  }        else {
                    invisible(this$eval(paste(
                      "var",
                      name,
                      "=",
                      toJSON(value,                 auto_unbox = auto_unbox, ...)
                    )))
                  }
              }    reset <-
                function() {
                  private$context <-
                    make_context(private$console)        private$created <-
                      Sys.time()        if (length(global)) {
                        context_eval(paste("var", global, "= this;", collapse = "\n"),
                                     private$context)
                      }        if (isTRUE(typed_arrays)) {
                        context_enable_typed_arrays(private$context)
                      }        invisible()
                }    console <-
                  function() {
                    this$eval("")        message("This is V8 version ", version(), ". Press ESC or CTRL+C to exit.")        on.exit(message("Exiting V8 console."))        buffer <-
                      character()        has_history <-
                        !inherits(try(savehistory(tempfile()),             silent = T)
                                  , "try-error")        if (has_history) {
                                    savehistory()            on.exit(loadhistory(), add = TRUE)            histfile <-
                                      ".V8history"            if (file.exists(histfile)) {
                                        loadhistory(histfile)
                                      }            else {
                                        file.create(histfile)
                                      }
                                  }        rc.options(
                                    custom.completer = function(env) {
                                      env$comps <-
                                        tab_complete(this, env$token)
                                    }
                                  )        on.exit({
                                    rc.options(custom.completer = NULL)
                                  }, add = TRUE)        repeat {
                                    prompt <-
                                      ifelse(length(buffer), "  ", "~ ")            if (nchar(line <-
                                                                                              readline(prompt))) {
                                        buffer <-
                                          c(buffer, line)
                                      }            if (identical(buffer, "exit"))
                                        break            if (length(buffer) &&
                                                             (this$validate(buffer) ||
                                                              !nchar(line))) {
                                          if (has_history) {
                                            write(buffer, histfile, append = TRUE)                  loadhistory(histfile)
                                          }                tryCatch(
                                            cat(undefined_to_null(this$eval(buffer))),
                                            error = function(e) {
                                              message(e$message)
                                            }
                                          )                buffer <-
                                            character()
                                        }
                                  }
                  }    reset()    lockEnvironment(environment(), TRUE)    structure(environment(), class = c("V8", "environment"))
})
10:V8::v8()
```

Here's my sessioninfo:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] V8_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 curl_3.1       Rcpp_0.12.15   jsonlite_1.5
```

I have [V8 3.1.14](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/v8-3.14/) installed on my system, and it was used to compile V8 R package.

**EDIT Workaround**

I have found a workaround for my issue. Here are the steps:

1. Install [V8 3.1.14](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/v8-3.14/) by running `yaourt v8-3.14`
2. Once you've done the step one you will have all files needed to compile R package so you can proceed with that (run `install.packages("V8")` in R console)
3. Now that you've installed V8 R package you can install [v8-3.14-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/v8-3.14-bin/) (by running `yaourt v8-3.14-bin`) which actually works instead of the one you compiled in the step 1. The two packages [v8-3.14](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/v8-3.14/) and [v8-3.14-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/v8-3.14-bin/) are in conflict  so they cant be installed on system at the same time. That's why you need to first use the one which has all the dev headers and then use the one with working binaries.

I'm leaving the question open in case someone comes up with a nicer solution.

**EDIT 2**

More info:

https://github.com/jeroen/V8/issues/32

https://github.com/jeroen/V8/issues/40

Comment: Sounds like something the developer can/should fix. Maybe post an issue: https://github.com/jeroen/v8/issues

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/jeroen/V8/issues/32)